# Are partially forgotten memories still in your brain?

Tags: memory, cognitive-neuroscience

I have read articles such as...

http://www.wired.com/2009/09/forgottenmemories/

and they say forgotten memories are still stored in your brain.  What about partially remembered memories.  For example, I can remember getting into a fight with someone but I might not be able to remember when, how the other person looked at the time, or how the exact motions played out.  Does your brain still store these details?

Comment: I think forgotten memories are not lost. Once in my work place, I felt like I recalled a previously forgotten memory of hearing the word farinata and later,I heard somebody say that word confirming that I really recalled a forgotten memory. If 20 times a second for 100 years, a random 1 or 0 flashes in front of your eyes, the memory of some of those bits will probably be completely lost from your brain. Probably very few people know how to answer this question properly. You could ask it on ResearchGate if you're a research or find somebody else to do so if you're not.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can people improve their memory by training themselves to recall previously forgotten memories?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/15787/can-people-improve-their-memory-by-training-themselves-to-recall-previously-forg)